# geometric interpretation of eigenfunctions of a vector field

Tags: functional-analysis, modules, spectral-theory, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X\in\mathfrak X(M)$ be a section on the tangent bundle.

What is the geometrical interpretation of the eigenfunctions of $X$. That is functions in $f\in \mathcal C^\infty$ with $X[f]=\lambda f$, where $\lambda$ is in the reals?

What is the geometrical interpretation of the spectrum of $X$?

Comment: the eigenfunctions of $X$ ??

Comment: do you mean the differential?

Comment: I meant in the sense of viewing $X$ as a linear partial differential operator on $\mathcal C^\infty$. So I'm interested in solutions to the equation
\begin{equation}
X[f]=\lambda f
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ may or may not be a constant or a function itself.

Comment: Do you really want to allow $\lambda$ to be a nonconstant function? If so then any nowhere zero $f$ is an eigenfunction of $X$, just define $\lambda=X(f)/f$.

Comment: That's true. I would probably want to consider $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. But also the other case is interesting. For instance for the case of polynomial vector fields $X$ of degree $d$ this equation is fullfilled by Darboux polynomials $f$ and $\lambda $ is any polynoimial of degree at most $d-1$.

Comment: At least one clear geometric interpretation can be given to the eigenspace of $X$ in $\mathcal C^\infty$ associated to the $\lambda=0$, which are the first integrals and all functions thereof.

Comment: @Marlo, do you have a reference to the result you have cited about the Darboux polynomials being eigenfunctions for polynomial vector fields? I could not find it through internet search engines and I am really interested in it.

Comment: @jobe, thanks for your interest and your reference request. There is this publication by Ferragut and Gasull \href{http://repositori.uji.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10234/149410/69426.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y}{in \textit{Acta Applicandae Mathematicae}}, where they show just this result.